# basic question about python code on NLTK(sent(), list(s), for ~in~)

Tags: python, nltk

I'm a python beginner. I know that it is very easy code but actually it is difficult to me. I'm sorry.

I find somebody's python code on the internet about word2vec for embedding the word.

The following code is that I'm confused.

There are 2 things I can't understand
1. why we have to use [ ] in line 2?
2. what is the meaning, sents()?

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
sentences = [list(s) for s in movie_reviews.sents()]
```

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) It is a list comprehensions. Link might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Answer of question no. 1
I think, it return code in list. [**Maybe**]

Answer of question no. 2
The send() method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another value

Comment: Bro, I am a beginner coder python.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33236435)